# Using dynamic type as MVC model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic

I'm trying to using a json as model and i created a custom view type for it:

```
public class BaseController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    public ViewResult UIViewResult(dynamic model)
   {

      return base.View(model);

    }
}
```

It is throwing this error:

> Error 2 The call to method 'View' needs to be dynamically dispatched,
>   but cannot be because it is part of a base access expression. Consider
>   casting the dynamic arguments or eliminating the base
>   access.   C:\Users\fcamara_assuncao\Source\Workspaces\Spring\Store\05-Web\5.4-Application\Mvc\Controller\BaseController.cs    29  20  5.4-Application

When I build, how can I use a dynamic object as model?

Comment: Have you tried just calling `return View(model)` there is no obvious value to adding `base.View()` unless you have a `this.View()` you don't want to call.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should use `ViewBag` in your controller like this:

```
public class BaseController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    public ViewResult UIViewResult(dynamic model)
    {
      ViewBag = model;
      return base.View();
    }
}
```

And then use `ViewBag` on your `View`. The problem why you get this kind of error, i suppose, is that compiler don't know which overload of `View()` method it should use.